# driving mileage between two zip codes

Tags: php

I have made a web page but I need an instant quote form or box that asks visitors for zip codes or addresses and we give back a quote for shipping.  I need the distance to be multiplied by the rate per mile.  Every thing I have tried has been straight line not driving. Does anyone know how to find driving distance between two zip codes or address both?

Comment: Your mileage accuracy can vary quite a bit depending on the zip codes used. Zip codes between two densely populated places where each zip code encloses a fairly small area will give greater accuracy, but between sparsely populated areas where one zip code encompasses a large area can be grossly inaccurate. People on the "near" side of a large zip code will be overcharged (or overquoted at least) and those on the "far" side will be undercharged.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [google maps api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters).

Do a call

`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false`

Parse the json output with `json_decode()`

Iterate each leg of the journey adding up the `distance` in miles.

This will give you the driving distance between two addresses. It will always be longer than a straight line, but it is accurate nonetheless.

If straight line distance between addresses is needed, you can use the API pull the latitude and longitude for each address, then use [this cacluation](http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.php.html) to determine the distance in miles or kilometers.

Comment: Add the distance "value" in meters instead of the distance "text" in miles, then convert to miles after all values are added to get a more accurate distance.